# Distinct items in List

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that I am trying to populate a list with only unique values. I have found [LinqToExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420911/linqtoexcel-distinct-values-in-excel-column) which I would prefer not to use. At most there will be 2000 rows which isn't very much.

My thought was:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
string item;

for (i=2; i<2001; i++)
{
    item = ws.cells[i,3];
    if(lst.**notInList**(item))
    {
        lst.Add(item);
    }
}
```

I know that there isn't `notInList()`, but I was hoping for something similar or another idea.

Comment: Have you tried if ( ! lst.Contains(item) )?

Comment: What's wrong with `!lst.Contains(string)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Contains instead

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
string item;

for (i=2; i<2001; i++)
{
    item = ws.cells[i,3];
    if(!lst.Contains(item))
    {
        lst.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var values = Enumerable.Range(2, 1999)
                       .Select(i => ws.cells[i,3])
                       .Distinct()
                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
string item;

for (i=2; i<2001; i++)
{
    item = ws.cells[i,3];
    if(!lst.Contains(item))
    {
        lst.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional explanation would improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the items filtered for identical entries, you could use the [`.Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method from linq.

```
var distinctList = lst.Distinct();
```

There's also [`List.Contains(item)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you know from the get-go that this collection should contain only unique elements, also consider using a [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.